# LINQ nested and/or cosmos db

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to build a LINQ expression for fetching data from my cosmosdb container using the CosmosClient SDK. It looks something like this:

```
p => (p.HairState.Density == hairState.Density
      || p.HairState.Density == nextClosestHairState.Density) &&
      (p.HairState.Porosity == hairState.Porosity
      || p.HairState.Porosity == nextClosestHairState.Porosity) &&
      (p.HairState.Texture == hairState.Texture
      || p.HairState.Texture == nextClosestHairState.Texture) &&
      (p.HairState.Thickness == hairState.Thickness
      || p.HairState.Thickness == nextClosestHairState.Thickness);
```

This does not work as expected. This on the other hand:

```
p => (p.HairState.Density == hairState.Density) &&
      (p.HairState.Porosity == hairState.Porosity) &&
      (p.HairState.Texture == hairState.Texture) &&
      (p.HairState.Thickness == hairState.Thickness);
```

works as expected. I'm new to using LINQ for database queries so I'm wondering if LINQ does not support such and/or nesting.

Also, is there a way for me to generate an equivalent sql query so I can see what exactly is going on? Thanks!

Comment: _This does not work as expected._ Exactly how does it not work as expected? Using the SDK you can get the generated Cosmos SQL as a string. You can then test that SQL using the explorer. By removing the "LINQ step" and experimenting directly with the SQL you should be able to determine how to create a query that works as expected.

Comment: Could you please guide me to a documentation or something as to where I can see the generated Cosmos SQL as a string? I looked through the FeedIterator object and didn't find an SQL string there.

Comment: You can use the [`ToQueryDefinition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.linq.cosmoslinqextensions.toquerydefinition?view=azure-dotnet) extension method. The `QueryDefinition` object has a `QueryText` property.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me debug my issue!

Comment: I will post answer to end this question.@ArvindSasikumar If you would like to post,I will delete my answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ToQueryDefinition() extension method and get the text of SQL query from QueryText property.Then you can test that SQL using the explorer and get the SQL query which works as expected.